# Wait for message using python's async protocol

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Into:

I am working in a TCP server that receives events over TCP. For this task, I decided to use `asyncio Protocol` libraries (yeah, maybe I should have used Streams), the reception of events works fine.

Problem:

I need to be able to connect to the clients, so I create another "server" used to look up all my connected clients, and after finding the correct one, I use the Protocol class transport object to send a message and try to grab the response by reading a buffer variable that always has the last received message.
My problem is, after sending the message, I don't know how to wait for the response, so I always get the previous message from the buffer.

I will try to simplify the code to illustrate (please, keep in mind that this is an example, not my real code):

```py
import asyncio
import time

CONN = set()


class ServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        CONN.add(self)

    def data_received(self, data):
        self.buffer = data
        #   DO OTHER STUFF
        print(data)

    def connection_lost(self, exc=None):
        CONN.remove(self)


class ConsoleProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        # Get first value just to ilustrate
        self.client = next(iter(CONN))

    def data_received(self, data):
        # Forward the message to the client
        self.client.transport.write(data)
        # wait a fraction of a second
        time.sleep(0.2)
        # foward the response of the client
        self.transport.write(self.client.buffer)


def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(
        loop.create_server(protocol_factory=ServerProtocol,
                           host='0.0.0.0',
                           port=6789))

    loop.run_until_complete(
        loop.create_server(protocol_factory=ConsoleProtocol,
                           host='0.0.0.0',
                           port=9876))

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is not only my first experience writing a TCP server, but is also my first experience working with parallelism. So it took me days to realize that my sleep not only would not work, but I was locking the server while it "sleeps".
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

time.sleep(0.2) is blocking, should not used in async programming, which will block the whole execution, if your program runing with 100 clients, the last client will be delayed for 0.2*99 seconds, which is not what you want.
the right way is trying to let program wait 0.2s but not blocking, then other concurrent clients would not be delayed,we can use thread.

```
import asyncio
import time
import threading
CONN = set()


class ServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):

    def dealy_thread(self):
        time.sleep(0.2)

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        CONN.add(self)

    def data_received(self, data):
        self.buffer = data
        #   DO OTHER STUFF
        print(data)

    def connection_lost(self, exc=None):
        CONN.remove(self)


class ConsoleProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        # Get first value just to ilustrate
        self.client = next(iter(CONN))

    def data_received(self, data):
        # Forward the message to the client
        self.client.transport.write(data)
        # wait a fraction of a second
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.delay_thread, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        # foward the response of the client
        self.transport.write(self.client.buffer)
```